# High level Python library for using Websocket and Comet "fallback" transparently

Tags: python, websocket, client, comet, abstraction

I'm looking for a High Level Python library for establishing HTTP connections to a Web server.
The connections should ideally remain open (persistant) for sending and receiving two-ways messages, so Websocket are great to me.
As I want it to be compatible will most HTTP proxies, I think about a "fallback" mode with HTTP polling (Comet style).

My problem is I can't find a library for managing these two kinds of connections transparently. Ideally, I would establish the connection to the server with one of the techniques (Websocket or Comet), then simply send/receive messages using the same functions for both types of connections.

I found many Python *servers* and some *Js* clients for that purpose, but not in Python.
I looked at : Twisted, Tornado, ZeroMQ, py4ws

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [socket.io](http://socket.io)? It mainly works with websockets but has plenty of fallbacks and is thus *supposed* to be supported by all browsers.

For the server side, I've used [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) together with [gevent-socketio](http://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Miquel Gringberg has recently released [flask-socketio](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO) extension which is a nice abstraction for working with flask and gevent-socketio. Gevent-socketio is built on the nice [gevent](http://www.gevent.org) library.

gevent-socketio should work fine with other Python frameworks, such as Django and Bottle.

I'm not entirely sure if this fits your bill but probably worth a look.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually took a look at socket.io and I will use it (or a framework based on it) for the server part.
My problem is I also need a client (not a browser) for performing some tasks. It seems to be possible with NodeJs (socket.io-client) but I'm looking for a Python library because I think it will be more maintenable by other programmers and easily distribuable

Comment: Which tasks do you need to perform that this combination is unable to?

Comment: This requires a client yes, and javascript to handle the browser side code but it abstracts the transport layer away entirely. Once you connect to the socket.io-endpoint, everything you do on the serverside is handled by the same functions. I'm not sure if there exists an HTTP library in pure python for this.

Comment: I think I actually found a solution. I will post the answer here. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I think Python Socket-IO client could be a good solution :
https://github.com/invisibleroads/socketIO-client

He can interact easily with a Socket.io NodeJs server, with same paradigms.

I tested it and it can default with Websocket connection and fallbacks to xhr-polling, which is great (I actually tested this features through a proxy).

Example :

```
with SocketIO('http://127.0.0.1', 7777, Namespace, transports=["websocket", "xhr-polling"], proxies={'http': 'http://localhost:8888'}) as socketIO:
    socketIO.on('foo',some_callback_function)
    socketIO.emit('bar')
    socketIO.wait()
```